# Explanation of Instructions behaviour

Tags: python, kivy, with-statement

I'm kind of newbie in Python, and I don't get the magic used by Kivy Instruction(s). For instance, following the docs, I developed my (naive) layout color background extension in this way

```
class BoxLayoutColor(BoxLayout) :
    def __init__(self, color = (0,0,0,1), **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayoutColor, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas.before:
            (r,g,b,a) = color
            Color(r,g,b,a)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)
            self.bind(size=self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)
    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = instance.pos
        self.rect.size = instance.size
```

it seems to work, but I wonder how the constructor Color() (because it's a constructor, I'm right ?) does influence the context. There must be something implicit that I cant spot from the Python documentation about the with statement...

And also, there is a way to group that functionality to be reused for other layouts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `with` statement is a generic python syntax that calls some special methods of the object you pass it (in this case `self.canvas.before`). When this happens, kivy's canvas sets a global variable somewhere, and unsets it when the with statement ends. When Instructions are instantiated they check if this variable is defined, and if so then automatically add themselves to the given canvas.

> And also, there is a way to group that functionality to be reused for other layouts ?

Kivy doesn't support this syntax for any widget manipulation, though it probably wouldn't be hard to add it. Mostly we use kv language instead, which has other advantages as well.